# Filling huge/large chunks of time-series data

Tags: python, time-series, data-science, missing-data, fill

What would be the best way to fill up missing values in time series data. Data varies a lot over working hours. The data is missing in huge chunks.

I have tried back back, forward filling and mean techniques to fill up the data. I have also tried interpolation( linear, nearest and polynomial) with pandas package. But results achieved are not very useful.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QLGiU.png)

First graph shows the missing data around 6-9 April. Second graph is plotted after filling missing values using linear interpolation.

What would be the best method to fill such a data? I am afraid linear interpolation will end up polluting the data.

I have read a bit about Kalman filter. Not sure how to use that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It really depends on the size of the chunks of missing data, but training a model in order to predict your missing values could work in some cases.
Apart from using `linear regression`, you could also try using other models, for example `k-nn regression`. In addition, the `datawig` module ([Github](https://github.com/awslabs/datawig)) uses Neural Networks to learn Machine Learning models in order to impute missing values in tables.

Kalman filter in python can be found in the `FilterPy` module. For more information you can read the documentation [here](https://filterpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/kalman/KalmanFilter.html).

Moreover, as you have time-series data to work with, you could see if an [ARIMA model](https://machinelearningmastery.com/arima-for-time-series-forecasting-with-python/) can do the job predicting your missing values.